# Javascript external file not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a article filter at the moment i can only seem to get it to work with internal javascript but i need to have it as a external javascript.

How do i do this?

When i add the javascript to an external file it doesn't show everything straight off and the active button doesn't work. I think it's that im not doing everything i should be in the javascript for it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<!-- MAIN (Center website) -->
<div class="main">

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('art')"> Art</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('design')"> Design</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('photography')"> Photography</button>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column photography">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Photography</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column design">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Design</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column design">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Design</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column photography">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Photography</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column photography">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Photography</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column design">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Design</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="column art">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Art</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
    <div class="column photography">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Photography</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
<!-- END GRID -->
</div>

<!-- END MAIN -->
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if you have some errors in the browser console, and chek if the path of the external file is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the src path is correct then your script code is executing with error. Your code with the internal script is executing because the script code are executing after the DOM elements are loaded.

Since you are referencing the external file in the *head* section the referenced elements are inaccessible because they are not in the DOM yet when executing script code.

Add the external file link at the bottom of the *body*:

```
  .....
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This will ensure the execution of the script code after the DOM load.

Comment: Thank you so much i have moved the script to the bottom and it now works

Answer (score 0):

put `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` at the bottom of `body` instead of `head`.

you are referencing HTML elements before they are loaded.

alternatively, you can execute your scripts after page is loaded using `window.onload`